# Filter pivot table by static filter without macros

Tags: excel, sharepoint, pivot-table, powerpivot

I have an Excel report showing a pivot table pulling data from a Data Model on Sharepoint.

I need to filter the report by each "manager" in the company(10 managers in total), so that every manager sees it's own report with it's own data.

Because reports are sharepoint integrated, i cannot play with macros.

What solution would you use to solve this problem?

My idea so far is to create a manager slicer, select manager, hide slicer and save excel. For a total of 10 excel reports. Not sure if that's a decent way tho.
I would also like to avoid creating 10 data models.

Any idea is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Can you graduate your PowerPivot model to a Tabular model? You can add security that allows each manager only to see their own data there. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213165.aspx

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, it looks good. Although unfortunately I won't have the time to implement it in this requirement.

Comment: The solution I've implemented was to add the field to the filters so that it pops beneath the table, then hide the row with 0 width. This also overrides any slicers. I know it's a non secure and non optimal solution, but it's what i had to roll with..

Answer (score 0):

gg.nz,

I would opt out for using PowerView for creating easy-to-use dashboards. That will allow you to easily manage users as well. Creating 10 duplicated Excel files can be quite time-consuming and updating them manually would be not a smart way to go since you have SharePoint & Office 2013 functionality available.

See [this post with detailed instructions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/power-view-in-sharepoint-server-create-save-and-print-reports-HA102834736.aspx) how to use PowerView dashboards.

Comment: I don't think using Power View would provide the data security he is looking for.  If he is still just creating 10 views filtered on a manager in the model (to keep managers from looking at other managers' data, it is trivial whether he is using Power View or straight excel as the visualization tool.